# What is the recommend location for storing compiled binaries for NON-admins?

Tags: unix, path

I know that administrators should be installing such binaries in /usr/local/bin, but what if a user doesn't have admin access? And/or what if a user wanted said binaries to travel with their home folder? Naturally, it would seem that any such location would have to be manually added to the $PATH, but I'm curious to know where other people are putting these?

Answer (score 2):

Small programs and scripts in $HOME/bin, and larger packages in $HOME/local subtree (which includes a bin folder)

Comment: Thank you. And what would you prescribe as the best way of adding this to the user's path? .profile? .bash_profile? something else?